# Gravitational field within a solid sphere with a hole on it

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-gravity

I want to calculate the gravitational field at $p'$, we know that the sphere has a uniform density $\rho$.

Basically what I tried to do to solve this problem was to calculate the potential exerted by the big sphere at $p'$ and subtract the potential by the small sphere at $p'$.

$i. \ g_1=\frac{-4}{3l^2}G\rho\pi R^3$ where $l$ is the distance $Op'$

$ii. \ g_2=\frac{-4}{3h^2}G\rho\pi a^3$ where $h$ is the distance $O'p'$

And doing some trig we have that $d^2=l^2+h^2-2 \ l\ h \ \cos(p')$

So the result will be $g_{p'}=g_1-g_2$

Is that correct?

[image: Solid sphere]

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you need to substract the potentials of the smaller sphere.Remember that in this type of problems they usually need approximation, and for example sin(x)~x, if x->0. One trick would be to convert from cos to sin and to apply the approximation.Good luck!

Comment: Thank you so much, I was having such a hard time trying to solve the equation that this approximation will make it way simpler.

Comment: He can subtract, but the potential inside a sphere was not calculated correctly

Comment: http://www.phys.uri.edu/gerhard/PHY204/tsl94.pdf

Comment: Oh, Bruce is right because when $r<R$ we have another behavior to the field and I completely forgot about it. Thanks to both of you.